# Whenever I open a .md in emacs, it immediately thinks it's been edited, why?

Tags: emacs

*EDIT:* I solved this by deleting the `markdown` folder in `elpa`, and reinstalling it. But I'm still not sure why this happened...

If I open and immediately close any `.md` or `.markdown` files, emacs immediately thinks they've been edited, so if I were to immediately close out, I get the "do you want to save it?" prompt.

This also happens on non-`.md` type files when I `M-x markdown-mode`.

I solved this, but thought I'd post an answer in case it helps anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I decided to re-install the package, and that fixed the bug, although I'm still not sure why it was happening.

So, in my `~/.emacs.d/elpa` I found `markdown-mode...`, deleted it by hand, went back to emacs's `M-x list-packages`, found `markdown-mode`, reinstalled it (type `i` when the cursor is on it), then type `x` to install all marked packages.

This fixed it.